# How to get the time of specified time zone?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I put my project in the hosting whose time zone is different from my place.

In my web project I use "Timestamp" to insert the time into my database. So I need to get the time of Chicago(my time zone).

I use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to get the time of different time zone.

My codes as follows:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime dtChicago =dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(dtChicago.getMillis());
```

However when I test it ,I found the follows print the same milliseconds

```
DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(dtLondon.getMillis());
DateTime dtChicago = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(dtChicago.getMillis());
```

So how can I get the exact "Chicago" time zone time and inject it into Timestamp?

Comment: A timestamp does not have a concept of timezone.

Comment: `DateTime.getMillis()` always returns the same no matter what timezone you set... It returns the number of millis since ""1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.". Why not just store the timestamp and then when presenting/using the value just convert to the correct timezone?

Comment: Use a formatter to format the TimeStamp in the required TimeZone

Answer (score 2):

> I found the follows print the same milliseconds

Doesn't that make sense to you? The *time* where I am right now might differ from the *time* where you are, but the *amount of time that has elapsed since [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)* is the same.

A timestamp is that *amount of time*. It does not have a concept of timezone. You can store it directly as you have it.

When you'll need to format it to show it to your users, you will provide a timezone and the conversion will take care of performing the time differential for the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a TimeZone into a Timestamp object. When interacting with a database, you need to provide a `Calendar` for both [setting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29) into a `PreparedStatement` and [getting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int,%20java.util.Calendar%29) from a `ResultSet`. The `Calendar` needs to be set to the TimeZone you want the data stored in the database. Normalizing all data to UTC presents many advantages for dealing with data from multiple timezones. It also eliminates the "hour of ambiguity" caused by DST when an hour is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get time of specified time zone with [**DateTimeZone::convertUTCToLocal**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#convertUTCToLocal%28long%29) method

```
long europeMillis = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London").convertUTCToLocal(dt.getMillis());  
long americaMillis = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago").convertUTCToLocal(dt.getMillis());
```